# Did Lana's ancestors migrate to America because it was the will of Isobel?

Tags: dc, superman, smallville

In the third Season of *Smallville*, Lana turns out to be descended from a Witch, Margaret Isobel Thoreaux, whose spirit takes over Lana's body. At first it is unclear to Isobel why she ended up in America and tells her disciples that it wasn't her intention to wind up there. But later on, she realises that the Teague family is also there and says that it was destiny that brought her to America. Now Isobel could only possess her descendant and since Lana is her only descendant and she lives in America, then of course Isobel was going to end up there. So was it Isobel's final spell that caused Lana's family to migrate, even if they didn't know it?